# Is it possible to use console commands to fix the "War Hero" achievement in the Civil War quest line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

After finishing the Civil War quest line in Skyrim I noticed that I had not gotten the *War Hero* achievement. This achievement can [apparently](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49631/27482) be missed depending on the outcome of [Season Unending](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending). As I am playing on the PC, I was wondering if it would be possible to use a console command to force start the quest that trigger the achievement? Since I sided with the Stormcloaks, this would either be The Battle for Fort Sungard or The Battle for Fort Greenwall.

Answer (score 2):

[Achievements Unlocker](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/16378) mod can unlock all achievements or any achievements you choose with a little Creation Kit modification (Available through Steam -> Library -> Tools). You can also use [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/) to add or remove any Steam achievements. All in all, these options are likely much faster and less bug-prone than messing around with using console to trigger alternative missions.