# Got rueful axe and all other drastic artifacts need help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to salvage Oblivion Walker Achievement after messing up Pieces of the Past](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49592/how-to-salvage-oblivion-walker-achievement-after-messing-up-pieces-of-the-past)

I have All deadric artifacts except from masque of clavicus vile where i took the axe instead. And the skeleton key where i completed thieves guild quest line. looking back I see rueful axe is not an artifact. Is there still a way to complete the achievement or not. As I'm on ps3 and have gone over the save, I'm level 81 don't really want start game over again for one mistake

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki (http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric_Artifacts), you only need to have had the artifact in your possession at some point, so you should still get credit for the skeleton key.  You can get both artifacts in the "Ill Met By Moonlight" quest (http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ill_Met_By_Moonlight), which will help in replacing one that is lost.  If that still isn't enough, you might want to check the list on the wiki page and see what you have missing.

Comment: The Skeleton Key doesn't count.